# How to organize logic for table-like feature set? Looking for architecture pattern advice

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, code-quality, architectural-patterns

I have a table-like feature set in a game. What it means is I have 10 types of **battle**, and 10 types of **features** related to battles, like hints, start/end logic, rewarding/spending resources, statistic etcetera. For every type of **battle** each **feature** has it's own unique conditions and outcomes, resulting in total of 100 individual logic pieces. I'm unable to come to any adequate arranging pattern for this logic. And I need this pattern for team of developers to follow, otherwise there is complete chaos. What's really important, these logic pieces should be working somewhat independent in several different module-based projects, where each project can or cannot include some of features and battle types. And for the cherry on top: not all battle types should have implemented a logic for every feature.

**1.** Initially I had a swicth-case statement in every **feature** for each type of **battle**.

pros:

- intuitive, easy to read (Clarity+)
- quick to modify (Maintainability+)
- every logic bit of a **feature** in one place (Clarity++)

cons:

- all **battle** types listed in one place (Cohesion++)
- necessity to modify code in every **feature** in case of adding new **battle** type (Extensibility--)
- no code pattern, resulting in freedom to add anything anywhere (Maintainability--)

**2.** For my next iteration I've decided to mirror that scheme and list all **feature** logic bits inside controllers dedicated for each **battle** type. I've added one interface covering all features. It's somewhat based on [Template-method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

pros:

- everything considering one type of **battle** in one place (Clarity++)
- adding new type of **battle** is easy, just need to implement one interface (Extensibility++)
- adding new **feature** is easy, just add new method to interface and be forced by compiler to implement it everywhere (Extensibility++)

cons:

- one class contains too much different logic of different **features**. (Cohesion+++)
- it's not clear where such controller should be located, considering module-based system of projects (???)

**3.** Now I'm planning to create a "table" of classes, each individual controller for each **feature-battle** crossing. For each **feature** there should be an interface, and for each **battle** type an implementation of such interface. Accessing such implementation would be through a special manager.

```
FeatureManager.Get<ISomeFeature>(BattleType.SomeBattle).DoLogic();
```

pros:

- full abstraction. (Extensibility+++ Clarity-)
- implementations can be placed inside module of a **feature** (Clarity+)

cons:

- huge amount of tiny classes (Maintainability- Clarity-)
- No compile errors in case of missing implementations. Need to develop new observer, to throw errors in case of some implementation missing, or existing when not expected, resulting in necessity to have small database with all **feature** settings. (Complexity++ Extensibility-)
- nesseity to develop a special manager for accessing logic. All logic bit must be registered to it's **battle** type by mentioning ID from enum BattleType.  (Complexity+)

None of these solutions seems good enough. So, what's the best course of action here? Thanks Internet!

Edit: here is a diagram for out projects and how modules are included [image: diagram]

Edit2: here is an example of that feature-set table. [image: example table]

Comment: Many large-scale games ended up implementing a scripting system, where the high level design (game design) can be done by editing a text-based script language, without having to rewrite the low-level implementation code.

Comment: All of your approaches are good ones at different stages of software development (i.e. prototyping). As the complexity of game design (note: game design is not software development) increases, there is an increasing need to decouple the complexity of game design from the complexity of software development.

Comment: [Template-method pattern (link: Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

Comment: *// one class contains **too much different logic** //* Have you tried to extract some of those logic into utility functions and helper classes, in order to keep the high-level code tidy and easy to read?

Comment: [Command pattern (link: Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

Comment: Thanks, @rwong! I agree with decoupling idea, that's why I'm trying to find the solution here, and the third "table" option is just about that. 

Text-based script language sounds fun and useful, although not all platforms allow that. IOS for example is rather strict about executing any non-native code, since it opens a possibility to alter application behavior on the fly and externally. So I'm not sure about that.

If I get it right, the "Template-method pattern" which you suggested, then it sounds exactly like my second solution. I'll update the text with that qualification, thank you!

Comment: // Have you tried to extract some of those logic into utility functions and helper classes // That will not help, since in that case some low-level class will have a direct call to high-level helper class, thus the problem of "one class knows too much" is still there. That is also makes the class unusable in all different projects that can or cannot include some of the features, listed there.

Comment: // since in that case some **low-level class** will have a direct call to **high-level helper class** // This can be solved using interfaces and reverse-interfaces (interfaces of callbacks), among other mechanisms. See: dependency-inversion principle.

Comment: yes, but solving it for every feature-battle crossing will require tons of plumbing code.

Comment: Are you able to add a diagram that illustrates your current architecture? It's a bit hard to visualize your complexity concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a shift of perspective can help you.

You seem to describe all feature implementations as "the so-and-so feature of battle type such-and-such". Is there some inherent concept about those features, that you have not abstracted yet?

For example, let's say your battles types have a ground feature that can modify movement speed. For instance in forests, troops move 50% slower.

```py
class BattleType:
  def __init__(self):
    self.ground = GroundFeature()

  def modify_troop_speed(self, speed):
    return self.ground.modify_troop_speed()

class GroundFeature:
  def modify_troop_speed(self, speed):
    return speed

class ForestBattleType(BattleType):
  def __init__(self):
    self.ground = ForestGroundFeature()

class ForestGroundFeature(GroundFeature):
  def modify_troop_speed(self, speed):
    return speed * 0.5
```

Now imagine we rename `ForestGroundFeature` by `SlowingGroundFeature` and add a bunch of others. Now you can compose your `ForestBattleType` from features that have meaning of their own:

```py
class ForestBattleType(BattleType):
  def __init__(self):
    self.ground = SlowingGroundFeature(0.5)
    self.visibility = DenseVegetationVisibilityFeature(density=2.5)
    self.random_events = DinosaurAttackRandomEventsFeature()
```

Pros:

- Linear instead of quadratic amount of functions needed
- Probably less code duplication, and more code reuse since features probably do similar things

Cons:

- Good abstractions are hard to find. The system may be more complex to code now, but should be easier to understand later.
- Using a feature palette is less flexible in the short term than free coding for every type/feature combination. You may need a way to combine features or just move to a more complex `BattleType` model than your 10-feature-slot model. It may end up looking like a  domain-specific language, as @rwong commented.
- I don't have a suggestion on how to compile-check this, but it may not be necessary since the `BattleType` implementations are easier to understand now.

(Answer to comment)

I took a look at your diagrams, Pavel, and I can't shake the feeling, that the table metaphor isn't the most helpful. Just having the grid fields makes people want to fill them in, even if nothing fits very well.

When I thought about the "feature palette" metaphor, I had more of a layer system in mind:
[image: Features and Battles as Layers]

I think, this promotes a more manageable code base. I'd start out with a simple scenario and add one implementation for each layer. Sometimes a single, well-generalized implementation may be good enough, others will need branching out. (Side-note: what the layers should optimally be is probably a very difficult decision. You seem to have thought about which parts of the logic need to be adjustable, which is good.) Saying from the get go, "ok, we'll need 10 implementations for 10 scenarios each" seems like an invitation for trouble. Whenever your architecture slightly changes, you will have to modify at least 10 places. As more Battle types or Features get added, this gets harder and harder.

Take my opinion with a grain of salt, though, I'm only three years in the industry ;)

Comment: Thanks @TheHowlingHoaschd! Yes, some features, like hints can be set by using a config file with some settings, and some features are using common API where possible. But that is not the case for majority of features, like server commands, validation, specific graphics or enemies. I've added an exemplary table of features to my question, to clarify that.

Comment: I think what you suggest with layers is closer to my first solution, with all it's cons. Imagine I need to add a new battle type - I'm going to search through all these layers manually and decide where I need to add what new logic. So this leads to lack of any pattern, which is making it increasingly harder for anyone to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have skipped a step in analyzing your requirements, because you're not leveraging the reusable parts of your code. Almost every column in your table hints at an interface/abstraction that can be made. I'll use a few examples from your columns in this answer.

**Entry fee** implies the need for an entry fee calculator. So what you do is you make a specific interface (`IEntryFeeCalculator`), and write your battle classes so that they can handle *any* `IEntryFeeCalculator`. For example:

```
public interface IEntryFeeCalculator
{
    int GetEntryFeeForPlayer(Player p);
}

public class PlayerLevelEntryFeeCalculator : IEntryFeeCalculator
{
    private readonly int _goldPerLevel;

    public PlayerLevelEntryFeeCalculator(int goldPerLevel)
    {
        _goldPerLevel = goldPerLevel;
    }

    public int GetEntryFeeForPlayer(Player p)
    {
        return p.Level * _goldPerLevel;
    }
}
```

I could come up with hundreds of different calculators. One that spews out a random number. One that calculates the price based on whether the player has bought the premium game license. One that calculates the price based on the day of the week. And so on...

But in all cases, the battle class can just expect to handle any entry fee calculator:

```
public class Battle
{
    private readonly IEntryFeeCalculator _entryFeeCalculator;

    public Battle(IEntryFeeCalculator entryFeeCalculator)
    {
        _entryFeeCalculator = entryFeeCalculator;
    }

    public bool CanPlayerRegister(Player p)
    {
        var entryFee = _entryFeeCalculator.GetEntryFeeForPlayer(p);
        
        // Player can join if he has the coin
        return p.Money >= entryFee;
    }
}
```

I hope the general outset is clear here. We defined a reusable behavior, i.e. calculating the entry fee, we created an interface that all our varied calculators will implement so that they can be used interchangeably, and then we make sure that our battle class only uses that reusable interface.

For the other examples, I'm just going to show you an example of what such an interface would look like. The implementations are up to you.

**Availability**

```
public interface IBattleAvailabilityEvaluator
{
    bool IsAvailable(Battle b);
}
```

**Environment**

```
public interface IBattleEnvironment
{
    void RenderGraphics();
}
```

**Rewards**

```
public interface IBattleRewardGenerator
{
    IEnumerable<Reward> GetRewardsForWin(Battle b, Player winner);
    IEnumerable<Reward> GetRewardsForLoss(Battle b, Player loser);
}
```

The others are similarly possible, though much depends on the precise details of how these things are implemented. I made a reasonable guess at the needed input parameters, but this of course hinges on your specific requirements as well.

---

So now we've got a bunch of calculators/generators/... and their interfaces, and we have the `Battle` class which works with these interfaces. So how do we put it all together?

Well, we could use a factory pattern to generate our battles with the correct dependencies:

```
public class BattleFactory
{
    public Battle GenerateStoryBattle(Player player)
    {
        return new Battle(
            new StoryNotCompleteAvailabilityEvaluator(), // IBattleAvailabilityEvaluator
            new StoryRewardGenerator(),                  // IBattleRewardGenerator,
            new StoryLevelEnvironment(player),           // IBattleEnvironment
            new PlayerLevelEntryFeeCalculator(5),        // IEntryFeeCalculator
            "Try gain better equipment"                  // Hint on loss
        );
    }

    public Battle GenerateArenaBattle(Player player, Player opponent)
    {
        return new Battle(
            new PlayerAvailabilityEvaluator(opponent),    // IBattleAvailabilityEvaluator
            new ArenaRewardGenerator(),                   // IBattleRewardGenerator,
            new ArenaLevelEnvironment(),                  // IBattleEnvironment
            new PlayerProgressEntryFeeCalculator(player), // IEntryFeeCalculator
            "Try go to encounter"                         // Hint on loss
        );
    }
}
```

I skipped the other dependencies, but the principle remains the same. First, you develop all your needed components, and then the factory assembles your battles using the components.

This factory is, in essence, using your table to put it all together. But before it can do so, you need to develop all of the features in that table (using the columns as a guideline for abstractable behavior).

Also, notice that the hint is just being passed as a string. This is to show that not every dependency has to be a class of its own. Sometimes it might just be a value that you pass into the battle class, without it needing to be dynamically generated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I think you answered a bit of a different question. First of all I've already explored the idea for an interface for each feature in my third solution. The problem with reusable code is not relevant to my question, since I can just call any common reusable logic from individual implementation for each logic.

Comment: The main problem here, as you said, is how do we put it all together? And you are suggesting hardcoding implementations into battle class fabrics, which is inconsistent with my requirement of not all features being included in each project. Meaning I'm going to need to create fabrics again for each new project, and that is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: How about this: define a separate factory for each project, and determine based on config files, which one to use. I like @Flater's idea of not even making subclasses of Battle. The assembly details can be specified by a factory method, and those can be changed based on project.

Comment: @PavelOliferovskiy: I strongly disagree with many of your conclusions on what is a good/bad approach. You specifically list a lack of clarity as a negative when supposedly using smaller classes - quite the opposite is true (up to a reasonable point of course, as with all things). Many of your conclusions are either wrong, misinterpreted, or rely on the assumption that there is only one possible implementation (i.e. the one you could think of) and completely ignore the possibility of any other implementation which might not entail the highlighted issue (e.g. your "battle enum" con in #3)

Comment: @PavelOliferovskiy: How you tie it together is up to you. I showed you the simplest way, which assumes that each battle type has an effectively hardcoded composition. You can use a config file for this if it's more dynamic. You could use a database. But the question is what your requirements are, and how complex you need your configuration to be. There's no point implementing a config database if the requirements are effectively hardcoded. This brings me back to my initial point, you've not completed (or fully communicated) your analysis and requirements.

Comment: @PavelOliferovskiy: If you want to specifically restrict access to certain implementations, then you have to implement some access restrictions. That much is obvious. Nothing is stopping you from spreading these implementations across multiple libraries and having each project only reference a specific subset of those libraries. But again, this isn't really hard to do _once you know what you need_, which needs both an analysis and communication of the requirements. I would suggest reevaluating whether you truly need to prohibit access, or if the consumer can be trusted to use what they need.

Comment: @PavelOliferovskiy: I genuinely don't mean to offend because I've been in your shoes, but there are many little bits and bobs that you get wrong, mostly related to what you label as good/bad and why. I cannot write a full counter on every little thing that is off - this is massively out of scope for StackExchange. But all those bits and bobs are leading you to conclusions about good/bad approaches that a lot of seasoned developers would not agree with. I offered as much as I can here, by showing you a sensical alternative that does not suffer from bad practice.